# How can I view Thunderbird in full Dark Mode?

Tags: firefox, thunderbird, dark-mode

Thunderbird is the only app on my Ubuntu machine which is not dark mode, and that makes it really annoying to look at.

I've installed `Dark Reader` addon, but it is not much helpful as it only darkens the individual emails, not the emails list and left column.

So I appreciate if you have a better solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Alright, I found my answer. Just needed to enable `Dark` Theme and it makes the whole thunderbird pitch black. Awesome:

[image]

Comment: So that's under `Tools` -> `Add-ons and Themes`.

Comment: its not making the actual email content dark though.. its keeping white background.

Comment: i found the "Dark Reader" add-on extension for Thunderbird, works perfectly